# How to set up stunserver and turnserver in icedemo?

Tags: c, pjsip, stun, turn

I am using pjsip project 2.3.and I want to use ice to imp my p2p.

so i compiled icedemo.c.and the cmdline is "-s stunserver.org".

but when i run the demo,i found it can not work well.
 the dump info like this:

```
11:46:45.343 os_core_win32.  pjlib 1.4 for win32 initialized
 11:46:45.359          pjlib  select() I/O Queue created (00A338E4)
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                    M E N U                                           |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| c | create           Create the instance                             |
| d | destroy          Destroy the instance                            |
| i | init o|a         Initialize ICE session as offerer or answerer   |
| e | stop             End/stop ICE session                            |
| s | show             Display local ICE info                          |
| r | remote           Input remote ICE info                           |
| b | start            Begin ICE negotiation                           |
| x | send <compid> .. Send data to remote                             |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| h |  help            * Help! *                                       |
| q |  quit            Quit                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
Input: c
 11:46:49.703        icedemo  Creating ICE stream transport with 1 component(s)
 11:46:49.734        icedemo  Comp 1: srflx candidate starts Binding discovery
 11:46:50.000 stuntp00A34390  TX 36 bytes STUN message to 132.177.123.13:3478:
--- begin STUN message ---
STUN Binding request
 Hdr: length=16, magic=2112a442, tsx_id=6784482372ae3d6c00015f90
 Attributes:
  SOFTWARE: length=10, value="pjnath-1.4"
--- end of STUN message ---
  11:46:50.000 stuntsx00A3BCF  STUN client transaction created
 11:46:50.000 stuntsx00A3BCF  STUN sending message (transmit count=1)
 11:46:50.015        icedemo  Comp 1: host candidate 192.168.2.146:7033 added
 11:46:50.015        icedemo  ICE stream transport created
 11:46:50.015      icedemo.c  ICE instance successfully created
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                    M E N U                                           |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| c | create           Create the instance                             |
| d | destroy          Destroy the instance                            |
| i | init o|a         Initialize ICE session as offerer or answerer   |
| e | stop             End/stop ICE session                            |
| s | show             Display local ICE info                          |
| r | remote           Input remote ICE info                           |
| b | start            Begin ICE negotiation                           |
| x | send <compid> .. Send data to remote                             |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| h |  help            * Help! *                                       |
| q |  quit            Quit                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
Input:  11:46:50.359 stuntsx00A3BCF  STUN sending message (transmit count=2)
 11:46:50.562 stuntsx00A3BCF  STUN sending message (transmit count=3)
 11:46:50.968 stuntsx00A3BCF  STUN sending message (transmit count=4)
 11:46:51.781 stuntsx00A3BCF  STUN sending message (transmit count=5)
 11:46:53.390 stuntsx00A3BCF  STUN sending message (transmit count=6)
 11:46:56.593 stuntsx00A3BCF  STUN sending message (transmit count=7)
 11:46:58.203 stuntsx00A3BCF  STUN timeout waiting for response
 11:46:58.203 stuntp00A34390  Session failed because STUN Binding request failed
: STUN transaction has timed out (PJNATH_ESTUNTIMEDOUT)
  11:46:58.203        icedemo  STUN binding request failed: STUN transaction has
timed out (PJNATH_ESTUNTIMEDOUT)
 11:46:58.203      icedemo.c  ICE initialization failed: STUN transaction has ti
med out (PJNATH_ESTUNTIMEDOUT)
 11:47:00.203 stuntsx00A3BCF  STUN client transaction destroyed
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. I think that this question could use a little bit of work, you need to add a [little more information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to the question and provide an example of what you've done already to try to fix it, and the code where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been having similar issues with my PjSIP based application. Something seems to be wrong with the STUN server at `stunserver.org`. It keeps going down from time to time.

Try using one of the STUN servers provided by google. I found them to be pretty reliable.

```
stun.l.google.com:19302
stun1.l.google.com:19302
stun2.l.google.com:19302
stun3.l.google.com:19302
stun4.l.google.com:19302
```